# Method GET with Axios giving Error 404. ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, axios, postman

**>Error: Request failed with status code 404,

> at createError (createError.js:16)
> at settle (settle.js:17)
> at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)**

```
     componentDidMount = (MYTOKEN) => {
    axios.get('192.168.0.10:9000/getquestions', {
      params: { 
        token:MYTOKEN,
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
      }
    })
      .then(res => {
        console.log("res" + res.data)
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e))
  }
```

Comment: Try `axios.get`!

Comment: No Its GET and post both are not working

Comment: And of course you already tried with Postman and it works right? I mean is this url `192.168.0.10:9000/getquestions` correct?

Comment: Try that url in browser, r u behind the proxy? try to log the error in axios-instance, it will show Network error if you are behind a proxy

Comment: I'd wager that `token` should be a part of your `headers` object, not axios params. Though an invalid token *shouldn't* produce a 404, it could be the cause of your problem depending on your server's policies.

Comment: yes this URL perfect running in Postman

Answer (score 0):

````
componentDidMount = (MYTOKEN) => {
    axios.get('http://192.168.0.10:9000/getquestions', {
      params: { 
        token:MYTOKEN,
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
      }
    })
      .then(res => {
        console.log("res" + res.data)
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e))
  }
```
````